# New Pandas dataframe from subset of current df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a Pandas dataframe with town names in one column. I want to create a new dataframe containing a subset of those towns. I have tried the following code but it errors:

```
crime[(crime.Region == 'Stroud') & (crime.Region == 'Gloucester')]
```

The error I get is:

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Interestingly, this code works if I use '!=' and create a new dataframe based on stating the towns I do not want in it, however there are considerably more of these and it seems unintuitive.

Comment: Please show the full error message along with a sample DataFrame. Also, `(x==a) & (x==b)` condition doesn't really makes sense?

Comment: @JohnZwinck - dtypes are all 'object'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to perform an OR rather than an AND so you probably want to have something like

```
crime[(crime.Region == 'Stroud') | (crime.Region == 'Gloucester')]
```

Comment: Does this explain the error message "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed."?  It seems something else was wrong in addition to this.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm guessing there was likely something else that isn't displayed in the question as to why the error message occured. Such as passing a Series when it's looking for a tuple. Can't say exactly why it was experienced.